# Rails - undefined method `find' for nil:NilClass (ActiveAdmin)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, activeadmin

Say i got 2 controllers.

advertiser_campaign and advertiser_ad.

I need advertiser_ad to be a child of advertiser_campaign but as i am fairly new to activeadmin (and ruby itself) i am having some problems. I am trying to do a nested resource using ActiveAdmin.

Code below indeed registers required routes

```
ActiveAdmin.register Advertiser::Ad do
  belongs_to :advertiser_campaign
end
```

BUT when i try to access /admin/advertiser_campaigns/1/advertiser_ads I get error

```
NoMethodError in Admin::AdvertiserAdsController#index
undefined method `find' for nil:NilClass
```

Which probably means that routes work quite well and problem is somewhere in controller.
I tried to overwrite ActiveAdmin controller by doing something like this

```
controller do
  def index
    index! do |format|
      @advertiser_ads = Advertiser::Ad.all
      format.html
    end
  end
end
```

But there are absolutely no effect. Although i see that controller attempts to execute my customly overwritten controller but encounters same error.

In my advertiser_campaign model i have

```
has_many :advertiser_ads, :class_name => 'Advertiser::Ad'
```

and in my advertiser_ad model

```
belongs_to :advertiser_campaign, :class_name => 'Advertiser::Campaign'
```

Any help regarding this issue will be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/gregbell/active_admin/master/ActiveAdmin/Namespace) says that any resource is registered under a namespace. From your example it looks that you're trying to make use of `Advertiser::Ad` class without explicitly specifying a namespace. Try:

```
AdminAdmin::Advertiser::Ad
```

Anyway, if that doesn't help, use rails console (check for registered namespaces/classes) to quicker figure out the root of the problem.

Comment: According to the docs you sent me, namespace is registered like this ":namespace => :namespacename", but that really doesn't do much except of breaking routes.

According to this https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/78 namespace is not required for creating nested resources.

Comment: Yes, it's not required. The point is to figure out what's the default namespace being assigned